# Remove "my cart" from side bar in blog page only in magento

Tags: magento, layout

I am trying to remove the "my cart" block from the blog page in magento, but i am not being able to remove only from the blog page. Whenever i try to remove it, it removes it from the whole website.
Is there a way to remove it from only the blog page?

The code that i used:

```
 <reference name="right">   
        <remove name="cart_sidebar"/>
        <block type="blog/menu_sidebar" name="right.blog.menu" >
            <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="blog/menu/right" ifvalue="1">
                <template>aw_blog/menu.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <block type="blog/tags" name="blog_tags" />
        </block>
  </reference>
```

Any help will be appreciated, thank you

Comment: Hello  add  <remove name="cart_sidebar"/> tag in  <blog_index_index> tag

Comment: @MagikVishal : Thank you for the answer, but it did not work placing the tag <remove name="cart_sidebar"/> in <blog_index_index> also.